# appinbrowser after minimize app and return is hidden in iOS ionic v3

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, browser

when opening a link and minimizing the app, the tab disappears

```
 const options: InAppBrowserOptions = {
      location:"no",
      zoom: 'no',
      hidenavigationbuttons: "yes",
      toolbar:'yes',
      hideurlbar: 'no',
      closebuttoncaption:'Regresar',
     closebuttoncolor:'#FFFFFF',
     toolbarcolor:"#1b2668",
     footer:"yes",
     footercolor:"#1b2668",
      presentationstyle:'fullscreen',
      toolbarposition:"top"
    }  
const browser = this.iab.create(url,  "_blank ", options);
```

i need the tab only show until closed with close button

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.